# How to protect hard disk?

Tags: password

I have 320 GB hard disk on my laptop and I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on 1 partition and another partition is reserved for storage. I want to protect that storage partition with a password. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by protect? Keep confidential, or prevent deletion?

Answer (score 2):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

[Package in Natty](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/309823)

From the website: Free open-source disk encryption software for Windows 7/Vista/XP, Mac OS X, and Linux. Some of the main Features:

- Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.
- Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive or hard drive.
- Encryption is automatic, real-time and transparent.

  More information about the features of TrueCrypt can be found in the [documentation](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/).

And to finish it off a nice (term used loosly...) [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYtUHUv59cA) on using truecrypt in Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

when you're creating new partition trough system -> administration -> disk utility, you can set "encrypt whole partition". Then, always when you will try to mount it, it will ask you for password.

[image]

you can backup your data somewhere else, create encrypted partition and put them back